# Unable able to use variable (python)

Tags: python, variables

I have recently tried to code a program sends me a email with specific files, but I keep getting this error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DedHex\Desktop\j.py", line 29, in <module>
    attachment = open(PathName, "rb")
NameError: name 'PathName' is not defined"
```

But PathName is... so I really need help with this as it took me a while to code.

My code:

```
filename = "bob"
def getpath():
    if os.name == "nt":
        # This is the Windows Path
        PathName = os.getenv('localappdata') + \
        '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\'
        if (os.path.isdir(PathName) == False):
            print('[!] Chrome Doesn\'t exists')
attachment = open(PathName, "rb")
```

Answer (score 0):

PathName is only defined in `getpath()`, and you're trying to use it outside of `getpath()`'s scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the PathName global

```
filename = "bob"
def getpath():
    global PathName
    if os.name == "nt":
        # This is the Windows Path
        PathName = os.getenv('localappdata') + \
        '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\'
        if (os.path.isdir(PathName) == False):
            print('[!] Chrome Doesn\'t exists')
attachment = open(PathName, "rb")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `PathName` is defined within `getpath()` , you need a way to access it outside of it.
`return PathName` will let you access what is stored in `PathName` outside of `getpath()` via `PathName = getpath()` .

The following code should work:

```
filename = "bob"
def getpath():
    if os.name == "nt":
        # This is the Windows Path
        PathName = os.getenv('localappdata') + \
        '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\'
        if (os.path.isdir(PathName) == False):
            print('[!] Chrome Doesn\'t exists')
    return PathName
PathName = getpath()
attachment = open(PathName, "rb")
```

If you have any questions as to why that works, I would be glad to go into more detail!